# Return Map Row NULL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to map a json response from mysql query, but i receive ho response: `data: NULL`

This is my code:

```
const audience = rows.map((row) => {
    db.query(CountAudiences, [row.campaign], function(err, count, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Query result: ', count[0].audience);
        return {
            id: row.id,
            title: row.title,
            campaign: row.campaign,
            action: row.action,
            date: row.date,
            audiences: count[0].audience
        }
    });
});
res.json({
    count: rows.length,
    data: audience
})
```

Response:

```
{
   "count":1,
   "data":[
      null
   ]
}
```

Do you know how solve this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code as you are placing a query, so it is a Async hit. Try this

```
 function getResponse(){
    let rows = [{ id: 1, title: 5 }, { id: 2, title: "ggg" }]
    const audience = rows.map(async (row) => {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
       db.query(CountAudiences, [row.campaign], function (err, count, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Query result: ', count[0].audience);
        resolve( {
            id: row.id,
            title: row.title,
            campaign: row.campaign,
            action: row.action,
            date: row.date,
            audiences: count[0].audience
          })
         })
        })
     });

     return Promise.all(audience) 
   }

  getResponse().then((reponseData)=>{
    res.json({
    count: rows.length,
    data: reponseData
  })
```